# Scrapy `ReactorNotRestartable`: one class to run two (or more) spiders

Tags: twisted, scrapy

I'm aggregating daily data with Scrapy using a two-stage crawl. The first stage generates a list of URL's from an index page and the second stage writes the HTML, for each of the URL's in the list, to a Kafka topic.

[image: kafka cluster for Scrapy crawler]

Although the two components of the crawl are related, I'd like them to be independent: the `url_generator` would run as a scheduled task once a day, and the `page_requester` would run continually, processing URL's when available. For the sake of being "polite", I shall adjust the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` so that the crawler finishes well within the 24 hour period, but puts minimal load on the site.

I created a `CrawlerRunner` class that has functions to generate the URL's and retrieve the HTML:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log, signals
from scrapy_somesite.spiders.create_urls_spider import CreateSomeSiteUrlList
from scrapy_somesite.spiders.crawl_urls_spider import SomeSiteRetrievePages
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
import os
import sys

class CrawlerRunner:

    def __init__(self):
        sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.curdir, "crawl/somesite"))
        os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'scrapy_somesite.settings'
        self.settings = get_project_settings()
        log.start()

    def create_urls(self):
        spider = CreateSomeSiteUrlList()
        crawler_create_urls = Crawler(self.settings)
        crawler_create_urls.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        crawler_create_urls.configure()
        crawler_create_urls.crawl(spider)
        crawler_create_urls.start()
        reactor.run()

    def crawl_urls(self):
        spider = SomeSiteRetrievePages()
        crawler_crawl_urls = Crawler(self.settings)
        crawler_crawl_urls.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        crawler_crawl_urls.configure()
        crawler_crawl_urls.crawl(spider)
        crawler_crawl_urls.start()
        reactor.run()
```

When I instantiate the class, I'm able to successfully execute either function on its own but, unfortunately, I'm unable to execute them together:

```
from crawl.somesite import crawler_runner

cr = crawler_runner.CrawlerRunner()

cr.create_urls()
cr.crawl_urls()
```

The second function call generates a `twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable` when it tries to execute `reactor.run()` in the `crawl_urls` function.

I'm wondering if there's an easy fix for this code (e.g. some way to run two separate Twisted reactors), or if there's a better way to structure this project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was possible to run multiple spiders within one reactor by keeping the reactor open until all the spiders have stopped running. This was achieved by keeping a list of all the running spiders and not executing `reactor.stop()` until this list is empty:

```
import sys
import os
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy_somesite.spiders.create_urls_spider import Spider1
from scrapy_somesite.spiders.crawl_urls_spider import Spider2

from scrapy import signals, log
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler

class CrawlRunner:

    def __init__(self):
        self.running_crawlers = []

    def spider_closing(self, spider):
        log.msg("Spider closed: %s" % spider, level=log.INFO)
        self.running_crawlers.remove(spider)
        if not self.running_crawlers:
            reactor.stop()

    def run(self):

        sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.curdir, "crawl/somesite"))
        os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'scrapy_somesite.settings'
        settings = get_project_settings()
        log.start(loglevel=log.DEBUG)

        to_crawl = [Spider1, Spider2]

        for spider in to_crawl:

            crawler = Crawler(settings)
            crawler_obj = spider()
            self.running_crawlers.append(crawler_obj)

            crawler.signals.connect(self.spider_closing, signal=signals.spider_closed)
            crawler.configure()
            crawler.crawl(crawler_obj)
            crawler.start()

        reactor.run()
```

The class is executed:

```
from crawl.somesite.crawl import CrawlRunner

cr = CrawlRunner()
cr.run()
```

This solution was based on a [blogpost by Kiran Koduru](http://kirankoduru.github.io/python/multiple-scrapy-spiders.html).

Comment: Is there a way to add crawlers to reactor while it is running? How can this be done reactor.run() is blocking?